# scikit-learn CountVectorizer. vocabulary_

Tags: python, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I have the following example:

```
sentences = ['Rashmi likes ice cream', 'Rashmi hates chocolate.']

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=0, lowercase=False)
vectorizer.fit(sentences)
vectorizer.vocabulary_
```

With the Output:

```
{'Rashmi': 0, 'likes': 5, 'ice': 4, 'cream': 2, 'hates': 3, 'chocolate': 1}
```

So what do those numbers stand for? I dont get it.

Comment: according to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html), it is "A mapping of terms to feature indices."

Comment: yes i have read this, but i dont understand it. how does Rashmi gets the Number 0 and likes 5 ? whats the logic behind this?

Answer (score 2):

The numbers represent the indices of unique words in sorting order. The sorting happens based on ASCII sort order. This means that the capital letters come before the lower case.
For more details on ASCII sort order, you may also refer to http://support.ecisolutions.com/doc-ddms/help/reportsmenu/ascii_sort_order_chart.htm

Answer (score 1):

It's the mapping from word to it's ID

When calling fit on a vector each word will be mapped to the value in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

from [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html):

> vocabulary_ : dict
>   A mapping of terms to feature indices.

**Explanation**:

vocabulary_ is a dict where keys are terms and values are indices in the feature matrix.

CountVectorizer converts a collection of text documents to a matrix of token counts. It produces a sparse Matrix of the counts of each word from the vocabulary. The Matrix shape is NxM (N is the number of documents (rows) and M is the size of the vocabulary (columns)). This numbers are simply indices of each word of the vocabulary in this matrix across columns.